# How to detect a firewall in Windows?

Tags: http, winapi, firewall, http-get, windows-firewall

My app needs to make a GET request to a website and I'd like to be able to know if it's being blocked by a firewall, and ask the user to add an exception.

How can I find out that my get request failed because of a firewall, instead of something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a good firewall, you can't.  Among other options, a firewall can:

- reply with one of several different [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) messages, indicating the destination is not accessible, or
- silently discard the request, resulting in a timeout.

A reasonable option is to explain why the app was unable to access the website, and provide some helpful suggestions:

```
    No response from www.site.com:
    * Your computer may not be connected to the Internet.
    * The site may be down.
    * The site may be blocked by a firewall.
```

```
    The network indicated that www.site.com is not accessible:
    * Helpful messages go here.
```

The important point is to differentiate, perhaps better than I did above, between the *types* of failure, and the *reasons* behind them.  For example, the steps for troubleshooting "no response" will be different from those for troubleshooting "the device told me it's not listening on that port."

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the internet with a short timeout... 
If the command fails, you can suppose that the machine has a firewall which requires user interaction.

If the firewall is good, you can't detect it.

Comment: Access _what_ on the Internet?  In general, the firewall is not on the user's machine; it's either on a corporate boundary or at the target's end -- firewalls (very generally) stop you from getting _into_, not _out of_, a particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32 Firewall apis (classic)